# MainMenu.OnJoinedRoon(): no suitable method found to override Photon Pun

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, overriding, multiplayer, photon

Im writing lobby script, there is a error in title. My code:

Copying scripts from https://youtu.be/EPJIJ_vTXu4?t=750

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Photon.Pun;
using Photon.Realtime;
using UnityEngine.UI;


public class MainMenu : MonoBehaviour
{
    public InputField IFNameRoom;
    public void CreateRoom() {
        RoomOptions roomOptions = new RoomOptions();
        roomOptions.MaxPlayers = 4;
        PhotonNetwork.CreateRoom(IFNameRoom.text, roomOptions);
    }
    public void JoinRoon() {
        PhotonNetwork.JoinRoon(IFNameRoom.text);
    }
    public override void OnJoinedRoom() {
        PhotonNetwork.LoadLevel("Game");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For starters there is a typo:
JoinRoom not JoinRoon